# How can i return additional columns and their values for duplicate records in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Currently the query below returns a list of duplicate records based on their name however i am unable to include additional columns that may have different values.

Is there a way to achieve this? For example, i could have a customer record with the same name but authored or created by someone else. I need to know who the author is so that we can prioritize which record can be deleted.

```
SELECT o.ObjType, o.name, COUNT(o.Name) as NameCount, o.Author
FROM customer as o
GROUP BY o.ObjType,o.name, o.Author
HAVING (COUNT(o.name)>1) 
ORDER BY o.name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by joining back to the original data:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT o.ObjType, o.[name], COUNT(o.[Name]) as NameCount, o.Author
      FROM customer as o
      GROUP BY o.ObjType, o.[name], o.Author
      HAVING COUNT(o.[name]) > 1
     ) as dups inner join
     customer as c
     on c.ObjType = dups.ObjType and c.[name] = dups.[name] and c.Author = dups.Author
ORDER BY c.ObjType, c.[name], c.Author;
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that however get the error `Syntax error in FROM clause`

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey . . . I don't have Access on hand, but nothing is popping out in the current version.  Does the subquery run okay?

Comment: The subquery on its own runs fine